# What is the best, most secure way to write to a named pipe in Linux?

Tags: php, c, linux, ipc, named-pipes

What is the best, secure way to write to a named pipe in Linux? Or, how can I make a named pipe secure?

Here's how I write to the pipe on linux using PHP:

```
$con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
fwrite($con, "UP\n");
fclose($con);
```

I wish to make it more secure.

This is how I create the pipe in C:

```
int pc;
char mode[] = "0777";
int i = strtol(mode, 0, 8);
pc = mkfifo(FIFO, 0);

if(pc < 0) {
    printf("Failed in creating a pipe\n");
    printf("Exiting...\n");
    exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("Success in Creating Pipe\n");
    chmod("/tmp/myFIFO", i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to make it **`secure`**? What are your concerns?

Comment: Well I just think that creating a FIFO is risky. Security issues may arise when using named pipes so I just want to make it secure. Please Correct me if I'm wrong. THank you.

Comment: Why would creating a FIFO be more risky than creating a plain file? Or creating an anonymous pipe with the `pipe(2)` syscall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`umask`](http://php.net/umask) to control the permissions of the files you create. You also have [`chmod`](http://php.net/chmod) in php as well.

However, you also have [`posix_mkfifo`](http://php.net/posix_mkfifo) available, which exactly fits your purpose:

bool **posix_mkfifo** ( string *$pathname* , int *$mode* )